# Extract Indices of Numpy Array Based on Given Bit Information

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bit-manipulation

My data are in the form of '32-bit unsigned integer' as follows:

```
myData = np.array([1073741824, 1073741877, 1073742657, 1073742709, 1073742723, 1073755137, 1073755189,1073755969],dtype=np.uint32)
```

I want to get the index of the elements of 'myData' where the following occurs:

```
Bit No. 0–1
Bit Combination: 00
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.binary_repr()` to obtain the string representing each element and from this strings obtain the elements matching your criterion:

```
end = `00`
s = [np.binary_repr(ai, width=len(end)) for ai in myData]
indices = [i for (i, si) in enumerate(s) if si.endswith(end)]
```

---

### EDIT: vectorized (and recommended) approach

After studying a bit more I found you can use `np.unpackbits()` after working with a `uint8` view of your array:

```
myData = myData.view(np.uint32) # not needed if it is already np.uint32
tmp = np.unpackbits(myData.view(np.uint8)[::4][None, :], axis=0)
indices = np.where((tmp[-2, :] == 0) & (tmp[-1, :] == 0))[0]
```

Note that the slices are taken according to the bits you are comparing:

- `[::4]` for the first 8 bits
- `[1::4]` for the 9th to te 16th bits
- `[2::4]` for the 17th to the 24th bits
- `[3::4]` for the 25th to the 32th bits

this sequence could go on and on if your original data type was `np.uint64`, for example, but in this case using `[n::8]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the canonical way is this:

```
np.flatnonzero((a & 0b11) == 0)
```

I.e. mask out all bits except the last two and get the indices where it's all-zero.

This is short, fast, and doesn't make any assumption about endianness.

Comment: Interesting, btw how to use in case of Bit No. 5–7
and bit combination 01.

Comment: @jean - For bits 5 and **6** and pattern `01` you'd do `np.flatnonzero((a & 0b110000) == 0b010000)`, see also [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14380143)